# Can simplewallet auto refresh?

Tags: transaction-confirmation, monero-wallet-cli

Sometimes after I send a transaction, I like to use the "refresh" command so that I can see how many blocks (confirmations) have occurred for my transaction.

Similarly, when I am expecting to receive a transaction it would be nice if simplewallet would refresh automatically on my behalf instead of my needing to type "refresh" into the command line myself.

Is there a way to make simplewallet auto refresh?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recent simplewallet has an automatic refresh, every 90 seconds. If can be enabled and disabled by `set auto-refresh 1` and `set auto-refresh 0`. To view current settings: `set`.

When this was implemented, I believe the default was disabled, so if you created your wallet at that time (not sure exactly when that was), this might be off, and you need to enable it. The default is now enabled.

Answer (score 9):

Simplewallet communicates with the daemon (bitmonerod) but only when you issue a command. For that reason simplewallet will not refresh until you enter the refresh command even if the daemon is online and actively receiving blocks. The traditional "refresh" command will end its task after your wallet has scanned the blockchain up to the current block height.

Although an "auto_refresh" feature did not exist in older versions of simplewallet it is now available. Based on GitHub activity, it appears that more refresh functionality will be included in the new official GUI now in development.

Comment: Auto refresh does exist in 0.9.4.0. I just downloaded the source and checked, see line 431 of simplewallet.cpp. It's a bit confusing because it is a flag in the wallet, so if you created the wallet with a version of simplewallet older than 0.9.4.0 it will be disabled by default, but can be enabled I think. For wallets created with 0.9.4.0 or newer it should be on by default I believe.

Comment: @jwinterm thank you for clarifying. I looked at the list of help commands and did not see it so assumed it must have been added to the source code sometime after the release of 0.9.4.0 My wallet was indeed created with an older version of simplewallet.

Comment: I downloaded the source for the tagged 0.9.4.0 release, and it looks like it's in there. That's what I was quoting the line # in simplewallet.cpp from.