# Recovering Cake wallet from a lost iPhone to MyMonero on Android

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mymonero, cakewallet

I'm a new here so please bare with me. I would like to know if both of these wallets are compatible. I don't know much about the tech side but have Monero I need to recover from my lost (or stolen) iPhone. If they are not compatible, what can I do?

I've downloaded the Monero GUI (I hope that's correct), but cannot remember the exact date I created my wallet. I have not yet started the recovery process because it looks a bit intimidating. The more I read, the more I get confused, so I decided to ask my questions here first instead.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

-Monero Muchacha

Answer (score 1):

The 25 word mnemonic seed provided by Cake Wallet is compatible with MyMonero. However, MyMonero will have to scan the full blockchain looking for transactions that belong to your wallet. This is quite resource intensive and therefore an import fee of 0.1 XMR is required, which has to be paid by another wallet. Put differently, it cannot be subtracted from the current wallet. Note that Monerujo, another third-party Monero wallet for Android, does not require an import fee *and* the seed is compatible.

> but cannot remember the exact date I created the wallet

First note that for a wallet like Monerujo, you'd have to use a `Restore height` too. If you don't remember the exact date, you can use an approximate date. If, after the wallet is fully restored, not all transactions show up, you can always redo the process with a lower `Restore height`. A list of sensible `Restore heights` can be found here by the way:

[What is the relevance of the restore height?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/what-is-the-relevance-of-the-restore-height)

> I have not started the recovery process because it looks a bit intimidating

It is not particularly intimidating if you (i) choose a sensible `Restore height` and (ii) diligently go through the steps. That being said, if you need any help, you can always open a new thread on [r/monerosupport](https://www.reddit.com/r/monerosupport/) and the community will help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the simple to understand explanation. A month later, still doing research on the same topic because I had forgotten I asked, brought me full circle to my inquiry on Stack Exchange. It made me realize that people do care and I need not be so shy or intimidated to ask question number 2 and the many more I'll have in the future. I love Monero and now believe in the Monero community. Problem Solved! -Monero Muchacha