# My balance just disappeared

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I purchased some coins yesterday which I transferred to my wallet immediately.

Today I created a 2nd Wallet and was trying to send all the coins from wallet #1 to wallet #2. I filled in all details, clicked on "sign transaction", opened a PGP.asc file and got the message "quantity of transactions: 0".

After pressing on "OK" to skip the message, my balance dropped to "0.000000000000". Now both of my wallets have a 0.000000000000 balance.

But the process tab is just showing me my purchase from yesterday, not my transfer from wallet #1 to wallet #2, even though I waited for 5 hours and restarted the GUI multiple times. I even went to the settings and pressed on "Rescan Balance". My coins are still not showing. Can you help me please? I am running GUI Version 0.14.0.0

Comment: Did you try restoring from the 25 word mnemonic seed (for both wallets)? Make sure to set a sensible `Restore height` -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/what-is-the-relevance-of-the-restore-height

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to send a new transaction using cold signing (from the "clicked on "sign transaction"" comment, because you omit all the details of what you're doing), this is likely what happened:

- you create an unsigned transaction (at this point, the wallet marks your outputs as spent, since it's sending them, but the wallet still owns those outputs until the transaction ends up on the blockchain)
- you sign the transaction
- you don't send it to the blockchain, or it gets rejected

If this is indeed the case, the first wallet still has the coins, it's just marked them as spent. They should show up again if you do two things:
- `flush_txpool TXID`   (in monerod, and replace TXID with the actual transaction ID for that transaction)
- `refresh`    (in monero-wallet-cli, might need to do it twice)

Since you're using the GUI, you'll have to exit the GUI to do these things. I think it may be possible to do them from within the GUI, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Comment: I dont have any transaction ID for my transfer from Wallet #1 to Wallet #2, it doesnt show up on History.