# Missing transaction. XMR sent to Monerujo wallet

Tags: transaction-confirmation, wallet, monerujo

I have a basic understanding and ability to deal with a number of cryptocurrencies and recently decided to acquire a small amount of Monero. I purchased via Binance and found a wallet (Monerujo), that I transferred XMR to. At least I thought I did. The transfer to my public address took place, according to Binance, but nothing is showing in my wallet. It continues to display zero.

I found a thread that contained a utility to use to confirm a transaction. I used this and received the follow response:

```
This address doesn't own output 0 with pubkey: 555b...7c9f for amount: Confidential
This address owns output        1 with pubkey: 238a...48ce for amount: 0.297602

Total received: 0.297602
Found payment ID: 0000000000000000
```

What is going on? Can anyone help me understand the above as well as gain access to my XMR?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried restoring from the 25 word mnemonic seed in Monerujo? Make sure to use a proper restore height, which you can get here -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/what-is-the-relevance-of-the-restore-height

Comment: I have tried but am I having no luck. In fact, it won't expect my 25 mnemonic seed. I double/triple checked and have entered it in a number of times as well as used various block heights and dates but keep receiving "electrum-style word list failed".

Comment: Are you sure you typed the words correctly? Can you check the words you wrote down against the seed in the wallet that is missing your transaction?

Comment: Additionally, see: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/ckdtim/improve_monerujo_rating/evor6xp/?context=3

Comment: I restored using wookey and BAM balance is showing. Must some kind of bug with monerujo

Comment: A few users were affected by a remote node being stuck. As a result, an erroneous wallet creation height was set and the wallet would not see the transaction. You were probably affected too.

Answer (score 1):

Each Monero transaction contains multiple inputs/outputs. It is not expected that you own all of the outputs of the transaction; only those destined for you.

The utility you used is reporting:

> This address owns output 1 with pubkey: 238a...48ce for amount: 0.297602

Which indicates that your address did, in fact, receive 0.297602 XMR.