# My Monero coins are no longer in my reinstalled Monero wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

I set up my Monero wallet in 2018. Having changed my computer, I recently reinstalled my Monero wallet using seed words. After successful reinstalling the wallet, there are no Monero coins in the wallet.

All my coins should be in the wallet, there were not left in any exchange.

Are there some other steps that I need to do to get back my stored coins please?

Comment: Please try again with a suitable restore height: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/what-is-the-relevance-of-the-restore-height

Answer (score 1):

You need to rescan. If you know roughly when you created / first-used the original wallet, you can speed up the scan by specifying a start height.